# Update query in SQL: command not ended properly

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update fare_strategy set sales_date_to = ’07-SEP-22’ 
  where dep_date_to is not null 
  and market_id in 
   (select market_id 
     from fare_strategy_markets 
     where set_type = ‘STANDARD’
   );
```

In the following query, I'm getting error as SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: did you try to remove the semicolon?

Comment: Yes, but it won't execute until I put a semi-colon

Comment: FOR mysql you are using incorrect single quotes throughout. but you have also tagged oracle so which RDBMS do you want an anwser for?

Comment: I want answer for mysql

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Try this simple change `update fare_strategy set sales_date_to = '07-SEP-22' 
  where dep_date_to is not null 
  and market_id in 
   (select market_id 
     from fare_strategy_markets 
     where set_type = 'STANDARD'
   );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change like this because in your query you used `’` this is not valid so i just change it to `'` so it's works fine

```
update fare_strategy set sales_date_to = '07-SEP-22' where dep_date_to is 
not null  and market_id in (select market_id from 
fare_strategy_markets where set_type = 'STANDARD');
```